# how to change the size of trigger and time selection box

Tags: extjs

[image]

As the picture show I want change the size of trigger and time selection box. I once try some methods but no use.

Comment: What's the version of ExtJS and the name of the custom component you are using?

Comment: Do you want to have trigger wider or what exactly? What is the second arrow about?

Comment: I want the trigger more width and heighter

Comment: I neeed your help thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, i built a fiddle: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hgc)
According to your image you're using Neptune theme, so did i. But you haven't provided a version so i used the latest one.
Lets start with picker size. Setting width was pretty easy, but height required some css works. I define picker sizes: `wSize` &`hSize`, and `fontSize` at the top of the function, so you can change it.
Now about trigger size. Well trigger comes with one image of containing all sort of trigger images inside, that could be displayed(focus, hover etc.):
[image]
So i had to change parameters for all of them. I have overriden ext css classes and the thing, that you must be aware of, is that its all about proportions. For example the default size of trigger image is 110x22 and it includes 5 images of 22x22 size each. I changed the size from 22 to 33 so i had to change everything proportionally:
background-size: 110 to 165
background-position(click): 44 to 66
background-position(over): 66 to 99
...(you can see it in index.html)

So if you're going to change the size of trigger, you'll have to do some calculations.
Still there are some components inside the picker which needs to be stretched to look good, but i think you can do it yourself by taking this code as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much ! i will learn you way to solve the problem

Comment: but now i have a new question it's also the extjs datefield question

Comment: There's a problem like I'm going to type in 12:05:08 and I'm going to have to type it in this format and if I type in 12:5:8 like that I'm going to get an error

Comment: I don't remember having timepicker on datepicker, so could you at first provide the code which includes this: [https://i.imgur.com/hW74Yx3.png](https://i.imgur.com/hW74Yx3.png)

Comment: i submit a question on stackoverflow you can see it